# pspice equivalent inductance calculation

Tags: inductance, pspice, equivalent-circuit

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to implement an equivalent inductance circuit with the pspice program.
The circuit-wide inductance in the first picture is 2m I think.
So I implemented and checked the equivalent inductance circuit, but there is no correct value. (Use parametric sweep to set the initial value of 1m, increase value of 0.5m, and end value of 3m to plot the graph.)
What is wrong?
On the graph of the last picture, the sky blue dotted line represents voltage of the first picture circuit.